# Anchor (<a>) tag not detecting and changing fill color

Tags: html, css, web

I have tried looking around google and stack overflow to understand why my issue is happening, unfortunately none of the methods worked. I tried adding the `!important` element to the css, but that too did not work. I thought it was my positioning for my icons, but I tried different positioning but it still did not work.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   code is here and linked to css 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="pageIcons">

        <div class="facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jake.stecklow">
                <img src="facebook.svg">
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jstecklow08/">
                <img src="instagram.svg">
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="twitter">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/JakeStecklow">
                <img src="twitter.svg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS for the `pageIcons` and the Anchor tags.

```
.pageIcons {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 97vw;
    margin-top: 40vh;
    height: 1.5vh;
    width: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 30px;
}

a {
    fill: #c2c2c2;
}

a:hover {
    fill: white;
}
```

Keep in mind I have tried doing the fill in the pageIcons instead of the anchor css.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: `fill` is supposed to be applied to the svg, not the anchor tag

Comment: So, `a:hover svg { fill: ... }` and `a svg { fill: ... }` should work.

Comment: @RenevanderLende should the `img` tag be replaced with the `svg` tag?

Comment: Probably. At the moment your SVG is being treated like an image (read: jpg, png), but you want to change the content of that image (its color). For that to work the `img` will have to be an `svg`. This will require you to learn how to incorporate an SVG in your document. Not that difficult, but a bit cumbersome when you have many little SVG's. Most pages that use SVG icons have those icons inside the main document, so they can access the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The fill property in CSS is for filling in the color of a SVG shape.
change the img tag to svg then apply color to it

Comment: They just become invisible, changed the opacity but still no luck.

Comment: Hi Rozhan, your answer is actually a 'comment' and needs to be added directly below the question. Posting it as an 'answer' will get you downvoted really soon... No biggy.

Comment: SVG images can be written directly into the HTML document using the <svg> </svg> tag. To do this, open the SVG image in VS code or your preferred IDE, copy the code, and paste it inside the <body> element in your HTML document

Answer (score 0):

I added the svg in the html file itself rather than using the `img` tag. So instead of the files linking like doing `<img src="name.svg">` I added `<svg ......> <path .....>` etc etc. Thanks for everyone's help!